# Android Studio - save cumulative score over all games played

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a basic quiz, where I'm able to get the score for each attempt, from my 2nd screen (QuizActivity) using the below:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    editor.putInt("myHighScore", mScore);
    editor.commit();

    SharedPreferences preferences2 =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = preferences2.edit();

    editor2.putInt("myXP", xp);
    editor2.commit();
```

I'm then able to get these values in my first screen (MainActivity) using:

```
    SharedPreferences preferences =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    int highScore = preferences.getInt("myHighScore", 0);

    SharedPreferences preferences2 =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    int xp = preferences2.getInt("myXP",0 );
```

But, xp is reset each time to the last value - what I need to be able to do, is store the total running value of all scores in a variable like xp, and add to it each time a quiz is completed.

Do I need to use more shared prefs here, storing the running value in the first screen, get it on the second screen and send it back to the first screen added up? Feel like I'm confusing the issue too much now. Any help appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem is you data coming in i.e. quiz values and update them each time in shared preference. So what you do is get the last data using shared preference and then add to the new value i.e scores or xp. Then save it in shared preference using method apply.

```
SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    int highScore =highScore +preferences.getInt("myHighScore", 0);

    SharedPreferences preferences2 =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    int xp =xp+ preferences2.getInt("myXP",0 );

SharedPreferences preferences =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    editor.putInt("myHighScore", mScore);
    editor.apply();

    SharedPreferences preferences2 =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = preferences2.edit();

    editor2.putInt("myXP", xp);
    editor2.apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `xp` variable is not global, so you must keep track and update its value manually. You have few options:

1. Create a class to store xp. And pass it around. Persist on destroy etc..

   2. Access the `xp` from preferences onCreate, modify as your app runs and persist it before switch between screens

Comment: Using xp = xp + pref.get gives error of xp might not be initialised, so I assume this is what you mean by the above. I'm new to sharedprefs etc so not really sure where to go from here

Comment: @user9739950 i deleted my answer as i won't have the time to edit it in order to give a full answer to your problem, but the error comes from the fact that you need at one point or another to initialize xp to 0, and the reason why i comment this answer is because i believe he gave you what i missed in mine despite this being incomplete aswell, you could do that with a class, initiliazing xp in the constructor and passing it around.

Comment: Any chance you can give an example of 2 please?